# Sorting 2d String array using java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a string 2d array taken as user input. But this code is working for some cases and not working for some.

The code is:

```
 public class Source {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] customerDetails= new String[5][3];
        customerDetails[0][0]="10";
        customerDetails[0][1]="Raj";
        customerDetails[0][2]="Chennai";
  
        customerDetails[1][0]="100";
        customerDetails[1][1]="Akshay";
        customerDetails[1][0]="Pune";

        customerDetails[2][0]="20";
        customerDetails[2][1]="Simrath";
        customerDetails[2][2]="Amristar";

        customerDetails[3][0]="30";
        customerDetails[3][1]="Gaurav";
        customerDetails[3][2]="Delhi";

        customerDetails[4][0]="101";
        customerDetails[4][1]="Ganesh";
        customerDetails[4][2]="Chennai";

    
        
        /*for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                //customerArray[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
            }
        }*/

        Arrays.sort(customerArray, (a, b)->a[0].compareTo(b[0]));
        
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                System.out.println(customerArray[y][z]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have given direct inputs in this code. I want to sort the numbers as String

Comment: It might be helpful to include expected output. And note: in order to provide a real [mcve] to us, it would be better to "hardcode" your input data in your code here. We dont know what data you read on your machine from your input scanner!

Comment: It looks like the first input is an integer, but in your compare function you are comparing them as a string. Can you confirm that you want to sort the array based on Integer comparison?

Comment: I want to sort them as String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting wrong answer because you were comparing 0th index of each row of 2D array which are String. So, according to string comparison logic the outputs are correct. To get the sorting order as integer, you have to convert 0th index of each row to Integer in your comparator.

Modify your sort method call like below which should work according to your expectation because `a[0]` and `b[0]` are converted to Integer before comparison:

```
Arrays.sort(customerArray, (a, b)->Integer.valueOf(a[0]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b[0])));
```

**Output:**

```
10
Akhil
Pune
20
Rajni
Hyderabad
30
Praveen
Delhi
100
Rohith
Chennai
101
Sam
Bangalore
```